# Как заменить в данном случае циклы, чтобы не выскакивала ошибка runtime-error(RE) при тесте? 59/60 тестов норм, ошибка на последнем

Tags: python, циклы, numpy, for

```
import numpy as np
    
def rocauc(x3):
    return [item 
            for sublist in x3 
                for item in sublist
            ]
 
N = int(input())
a = [[float(i) for i in input().split()] for _ in range(N)]
 
floating_a = rocauc(a)
 
x1 = np.array(floating_a[::2])
 
x2 = np.array(floating_a[1::2])

x11, x12 = np.meshgrid(x1, x1)
x21, x22 = np.meshgrid(x2, x2)
 
x_condition = (x11>x12)

final = ((np.sum(x_condition & (x21 > x22))+ np.sum(x_condition & (x21 == x22))*0.5) / np.sum(x_condition))

print("%.6f" % final)
```

Comment: Задача то какая? Может там деление на ноль выходит.

Comment: Формат ввода

В первой строке указано одно число N — число объектов в выборке (). В каждой из следующих N строк указаны два вещественных числа (с точностью не более 6 цифр после десятичной точки): правильный ответ примера ti и предсказание модели yi для этого примера.

Гарантируется, что существуют два таких номера i и j, что ti ≠ tj. 
Формат вывода

Выведите одно число (значение обобщённого AUC) с точностью как минимум 6 значащих цифр после десятичной точки.

Comment: Пример 1

Ввод

2
0 0
1 1

Вывод

1.000000